# Django model's value depending on other model's value

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible that in Django value from one model depends on value from other model?

I have an app "godzina"

```
from django.db import models

class Godzina (models.Model):
    godzina = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Wybierz godzine w ktorej odbeda sie egzaminy')
```

Is it possible that after I add some values to this model. For example 16:00, 17:00, 19:00

Those values will be defined automatic in this model?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    GODZINA = (
        ('15:00', '15:00'),
        ('19:00', '19:00'),

    )
    godzina = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GODZINA, verbose_name='preferowana godzina egzaminu')
```

Comment: Why don't you create a `ForeignKey` column for `godzina` on `UserProfile`?

Comment: I don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

To provide code implementing what @ozgur suggested:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    godzina = models.ForeignKey('Godzina')
```

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey